# Keeping track of class objects in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object

How would one go about keeping track of a classes objects by pushing the new instances to an Array, and to allow this array to be edited/popped by an object of another class.

For example;

- > The object 'airplane' (Plane class) is created, and pushed to an Array called 'in-flight'.
- > The object 'airport' (Airport class) asks it to land and pops from the array.

Is there a way to do so, with and/or without the use of class variables?

Comment: Use a factory method to create airplane objects, instead of creating them  directly with `.new`. This factory method, beside creation of objects, can also register them in some array or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by overriding the `initialize` method of the `Airplane` class. Something like this:

```
class Airplane
  class << self
    attr_accessor :in_flight
  end
  self.in_flight ||= []

  def initialize(*)
    self.class.in_flight << self
    super
  end

  def land!
    self.class.in_flight.delete(self)
  end
end
```

then, from anywhere else in your codebase, do something like this:

```
# We'll just pick a random airplane from the list of those in
# flight, but presumably you would have some sort of logic around
# it (already have an Airplane instance somehow, select one from
# the array according to some criteria, etc).
airplane = Airplane.in_flight.sample
airplane.land!
```

Not sure that this is the greatest application design in the world, but it will certainly do if your needs are simple.